# Is there a characterization of integral domains where every element belong to at most finitely many prime ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is there a characterization, by mean of usual concepts like Noetherianity etc.,  of integral domains where every non zero element belongs to at most finitely many prime ideals?

Dedekind domains fulfill this condition.

Also, a domain where any intersection of an infinite number of prime ideals is void, fulfills this condition (in such a domain, every ideal would be contained in finitely many prime ideals).

Comment: Even domains with only finitely many prime ideals do not have an easy description.  Every finite poset is the poset of prime ideals in some ring.  So if you take any finite poset with a least element and then mod out the least prime in the corresponding ring, you get a domain with that poset of prime ideals.  It seems plausible there could be some useful characterization if you restrict to Noetherian domains.